# How to insert ListView in CardView with scrollbar outside CardView?

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar, material-design, android-cardview

I'm trying to implement ListView inside the new Widget CardView. I want to achieve the same result of Chrome when I do a search on Google. I post you a screen to let you know what I mean.
[Screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8B2lUo_b2W0aHNsNHpRbmdsRm8/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see, there are two cards. The results of search are shown in the second card and the scrollbar is not in the card, but outside. In my implementation, instead, the scrollbar is inside card and so the ListView items scroll inside the card!

I post my code:

xml layout (fragment_home.xml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view_search_2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/search_parameters_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment JAVA:

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment 
{

    private ListView mListView;

    private String[] stringValues;

    private SearchListItem searchItem;



    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_parameters_list);

        stringValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.search_parameters);

        parameters = new ArrayList<SearchListItem>();


        for(int i = 0; i < stringValues.length; ++i)
        {
            parameters.add(new SearchListItem(stringValues[i], ""));
        }   

        ListViewSearchAdapter adapter = new ListViewSearchAdapter(getActivity(), parameters);

        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion to make the same result in the screen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think Chrome use a list of CardView (CardView represent row of the lsit) and not a list inside the CardView. Take a look at this example: http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think you're right, but I tried defining a xml with the layout of the single row and inflating this throw a custom adapter. The result has been a list of cards, but I would like the cards were not separated. I've also defined an xml attributes for ListView: android:dividerHeight="0dp", android:divider="@null", but cards are always separated.

Comment: Of curse because you are changing list divider and not the card layout. I suggest you to do it in this way: in your adapter, in getView() method, get the CardView layout (the row of the list) and try to change his padding http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3apadding

Comment: Google Inbox app and website both use nonsrollable list of items in big card views. Just FYI.